# How does co-adaptation occur in deep neural nets

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, overfitting, backpropagation

From what I can understand, it describes the phenomenon of when neurons detect the same features. Why does this happen?

Comment: From Hinton's paper: "complex co-adaptation is a phenomena where a feature detector is only helpful in the context of several other specific feature detectors." So it is not learning the same features.

Answer (score 2):

Since the weights are not initialized properly and groups of neurons end up in the same local minima, according to their (similar) initialization.

To overcome this, you could use dropout / drop connect to break symmetry.

Hinton, G. E., Srivastava, N., Krizhevsky, A., Sutskever, I., & Salakhutdinov, R. R. (2012). Improving neural networks by preventing co-adaptation of feature detectors.

Comment: What does it mean for a neuron to be in a local minimum?